# Find overall min and max values in aggregate group results with single query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I've an object stored into my collection that looks like this:

```
[{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("56bcbe570793be2e5025567e"),   
    "CarPlate" : "AB123CD", 
    "Brand" : "BMW", 
    "Version" : "316d", 
    "Description" : "BMW 316d", 
    "Prices" : [
        {
            "PriceType" : NumberInt(0), 
            "VatType" : NumberInt(0), 
            "Currency" : "EUR", 
            "Value" : 20100.0
        }, 
        {
            "PriceType" : NumberInt(3), 
            "VatType" : NumberInt(0), 
            "Currency" : "EUR", 
            "Value" : 23900.0
        }, 
        {
            "PriceType" : NumberInt(4), 
            "VatType" : null, 
            "Currency" : "EUR", 
            "Value" : 30950.0
        }
    ]
}, { 
    "_id" : ObjectId("56bcbe570793be2e5025567f”),   
    "CarPlate" : "AB123CE”, 
    "Brand" : "BMW", 
    "Version" : "318d", 
    "Description" : "BMW 318d", 
    "Prices" : [
        {
            "PriceType" : NumberInt(0), 
            "VatType" : NumberInt(0), 
            "Currency" : "EUR", 
            "Value" : 23900.0
        }, 
        {
            "PriceType" : NumberInt(3), 
            "VatType" : NumberInt(0), 
            "Currency" : "EUR", 
            "Value" : 23900.0
        }, 
        {
            "PriceType" : NumberInt(4), 
            "VatType" : null, 
            "Currency" : "EUR", 
            "Value" : 40250.0
        }
    ]
}]
```

I'd like to retrieve the min and max price values [for the entire collection] where PriceType is equal to 4 using a single query.

I found a way to do that but running two different queries (basically the same query but with a different sort)

```
db.Cars.aggregate(
  [
    {
      $unwind: '$Prices'
    },
    {
      $match: {
      'Prices.PriceType': 4
      }
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: '$CarPlate',
        valueMin: { $min: '$Prices.Value' },
        valueMax: { $max: '$Prices.Value' }
      }
    },
    {
      $sort: {
        valueMin: 1
      }
    },
    {
      $limit: 1
    }
  ]
);
```

Any hint?

Comment: to clarify you want to find min and max for each car/document/object throughout the collection? or one min and one max from the whole collection

Comment: To the whole collection

Comment: So based on your example data you want a result something like this? `{ min: 20100.0, max: 40250.0 }`

Comment: Yeah, that's right.

One record with the highest price and the lowest of the entire collection

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
> db.Cars.aggregate([
                    {
                       $unwind:"$Prices"
                    }, 
                    {
                       $match:{"Prices.PriceType":4}
                    }, 
                    {
                       $group:
                        {_id:"$CarPlate", 
                          max_price:{$max:"$Prices.Value"}, 
                          min_price:{$min:"$Prices.Value"}
                        }
                    }, 
                   {
                       $group:
                       {_id:null, 
                        max_value:{$max:"$max_price"}, 
                        min_value:{$min:"$min_price"}
                       }
                   }
                  ])
```

This will output single value with min and max in the whole collection.

Comment: Seems good!
Thanks, let me try to convert it to c# but running on the shell it works

Comment: Nice, glad it helps.

Comment: You can optimize this query by adding an index on Prices.PricesType and by adding another $match before the $unwind to keep only documents that have at least one Prices with this PriceType in the array. The same $match after the unwind is still required of course but this one won't benefit from the index. That will make the $unwind + $match faster but it depends of your dataset. If 100% of your data have a PriceType=4, it won't help.

Comment: unfortunately all my data have the PriceType =4

Answer (score 1):

For all people who would know how to convert to c# a query like this (thanks again to @ibininja) here the c# code:

```
this.carRepository
    .Collection
    .Aggregate()
    .Match(priceTypeFilder)
    .Unwind<Car, CarToPrice>(i => i.Prices)
    .Match(x => x.Prices.PriceType == PriceTypeEnum.Catalog)
    .Group(key =>  key.CarPlate ,
    g => new
    {
        _id = g.Key,
        MinPrice = g.Min(o => o.Prices.Value),
        MaxPrice = g.Max(o => o.Prices.Value)
    })
    .Group(key => key._id,
    g => new
    {
        _id = (string)null,
        MinPrice = g.Min(o => o.MinPrice),
        MaxPrice = g.Max(o => o.MaxPrice)
    })
    .SingleAsync();
```